# How to deal with shell commands that never stops

Tags: ruby, bash, sh

Here is the case;
There is this app called "termux" on android which allows me to use a terminal on android, and one of the addons are androids API's like sensors, tts engines, etc.

I wanted to make a script in ruby using this app, specifically this api, but there is a catch:

The script:

```ruby
require('json')

JSON.parse(%x'termux-sensor -s "BMI160 Gyro" -n 1')
```

- -s = Name or partially the name of the sensor
- -n = Count of times the command will run

returns me:

```ruby
{
   "BMI160 Gyroscope" => {
      "values" => [
         -0.03...,
         0.00...,
         1.54...
      ]
   }
}
```

I didn't copied and pasted the values, but that's not the point, the point is that this command takes almost a full second the load, but there is a way to "make it faster"

If I use the argument "-d" and not use "-n", I can specify the time in milliseconds to delay between data being sent in STDOUT, it also takes a full second to load, but when it loads, the delay works like charm

And since I didn't specify a 'n' number of times, it never stops, and there is the problem

---

### How can I retrieve the data continuously in ruby??

I thought about using another thread so it won't stop my program, but how can I tell ruby to return the last X lines of the STDOUT from a command that hasn't and will not ever stop since "%x'command'" in ruby waits for a return?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out a built in module that saved me called [PTY](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html) and the [spawn#method](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.5.3/libdoc/pty/rdoc/PTY.html#method-c-spawn) plus thread management helped me to keep a variable updated with the command values each time the command outputted new bytes

Answer (score 0):

If I understood you need to connect to stdout from a long running process.

see if this works for your scenario using [IO.popen](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/IO.html#method-c-popen):

```rb
# by running this program
# and open another terminal 
# and start writing some data into data.txt
# you will see it appearing in this program output
#  $ date >> data.txt

io_obj = IO.popen('tail -f ./data.txt')
while !io_obj.eof?
  puts io_obj.readline
end
```